# How to use lineto() in canvas to draw but only over areas within specific color range

Tags: javascript, canvas

I tried to draw a line between two points in canvas, but I would like to have the line only covers the area within specific color range.

For example,

I will draw a line from point(0,5) to point(3,5), along the line there are three points with RGB (1,2,3) (4,5,6) and (7,8,9). My color range will be R value from 1 to 4. So I expect the line will be covering point(0,5) and point(1,5) but not for point(3,5).

How can I implement it?